# Get value in other rows as an additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show the number of shares outstanding as of today, side by side with number of shares of the same companies 1 year ago (t-12 months) . Here is the table with data as of today (2023-09-04).

| Company | Date | Shares Outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-09-04 | 1,000,000 |
| A | 2023-03-04 | 1,000,000 |
| A | 2022-09-04 | 950,000 |
| B | 2023-09-04 | 2,000,000 |
| B | 2023-03-04 | 2,100,000 |
| B | 2022-09-04 | 2,200,000 |

Need the SQL that outputs the following result set. Thank you!

| Company | Date | Shares Outstanding today | Shares Outstanding t-12 months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-09-04 | 1,000,000 | 950,000 |
| B | 2023-09-04 | 2,000,000 | 2,200,000 |

---

The question stated more specifically below:

Please see the screenshot. Am trying to list historical prices of company stocks side by side. Here I am listing today's price and price from 2 months ago (pe_2m) side by side. In the below screenshot I'm trying to use dateadd() function. But for some reason, dateadd() does not return the value. I know the value indeed exists in the table. please see the sqls and their result sets. Wondering why it is not working. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfSsz.png)

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question - why can't you get your output? Post your current attempt and explain why it's not working.

Comment: Does your data have an entry for every company for every day?  If so look at `LAG` partitioned by `Company` with an offset of 365/366

Comment: If you don't have data for every company for every day an `outer apply` can be used to run a correlated sub-query to locate the data at t-12 months, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think this CTE will do the trick. My thought process is get the most recent statement for each company (despite the sample data I’m not sure if this will ever vary between companies, so I grouped by company and grabbed the max date).

Next we retrieve the corresponding entry for the company 12 months ago — note you may have to do some additional manipulation here if your real data has more than one entry for each company every month. If you’re looking for the exact day on the previous year we can simply use `DateAdd(year, -1,CurrentData.Date) = SharesTable.Date` instead of `datediff(month,CurrentData.Date, sharesTable.Date) = -12`.

Finally we join these two tables together on company to get our results side by side.

```
With CurrentData As
(
   Select 
   SharesTable.*
   FROM SharesTable
   Join
   (
      Select 
      Company
      MAX(date) as mrDate
      From sharesTable
      Group by company 
   ) mrStatement 
   ON sharesTable.Company =  mrStatement.Company 
   AND sharesTable.Date = mrStatement.mrDate
)
,lastYearsData AS 
(
     Select 
     SharesTable.*
     From SharesTable
     Join CurrentData
     ON SharesTable.company =  CurrentData.company 
     AND datediff(month,CurrentData.Date, sharesTable.Date) = -12
)

Select 
CurrentData.Company
,CurrentData.Date
,CurrentData.SharesOutstanding As “Shares Outstanding Today” 
,lastYearsData.SharesOutstanding As “Shares Outstanding t -12 months”
From CurrentData
Join lastYearsData 
ON CurrentData.Company = lastYearsData.Company
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved my problem: Moved dateadd() to the other side of the join. Please see below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnvc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).